# How to disable audio capabilities for entire app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-video-player

I have an app that plays videos using the video_player package. These videos have sound, but I don't want to play it. To achieve this, I use:

```
controller.setVolume(0.0)
```

The problem is whenever I open the app, even before playing a video, any background music stops.

I figure there must be a way to say "this app does not have sound capability" and then the OS won't pause any background music.

Is there a flutter specific way to do this, or should I look for iOS and Android specific solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using AVAudioSession [setCategory](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616442-setcategory), with catergory `playback` and option `mixWithOthers`?

Comment: Do you know a flutter generic way to do this? This seems to be Apple specific.